# Missing class properties transform

Tags: reactjs, meteor

So i have just tried to get the google material dialog box.
I am very new to meteor and react so the answare might be more obvious for you then for me.

even so, my console are giving me this error:

```
Missing class properties
   transform.
```

on line 16 in this file:

```
export default class DialogExampleCustomWidth extends React.Component {

  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open: true});
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({open: false});
  };

  render() {
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton label="Dialog With Custom Width" onTouchTap={this.handleOpen} />
        <Dialog
          title="Dialog With Custom Width"
          actions={actions}
          modal={true}
          contentStyle={customContentStyle}
          open={this.state.open}
        >
          This dialog spans the entire width of the screen.
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the error appears on the `state = {`
i have read on multiple articals but can't seem to get it. Thank you for your help and time

Comment: Instance properties are not standardised in JS. You need to initialise your state in the constructor. `constructor() { this.state = ... }`

Comment: it says 'this' is not allowed before a super @zerkms

Comment: so - call `super()`?

Comment: For anyone else who finds this question and also uses SublimeText. After fixing this issue thanks to @henk 's answer, I then followed [Dan Abramov's blog post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/lint-like-it-s-2015-6987d44c5b48) for fixing the ESLint / Babel linting in SublimeText - which otherwise just throws an error at the `state = {` line and goes no further.

Answer (score 9):

Meteor does not support arrow functions by default, but today you can simply change that:

[add the following package:](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

```
meteor npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

Edit your package.json in your project and add there the following to make [the package work:](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#top)

```
 "babel": {
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]

  }
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly. Nitpicking, but arrow functions are supported through meteor, just class properties aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Change your codes like this:

```
export default class DialogExampleCustomWidth extends React.Component {

  consructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
  };

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open: true});
  };

  ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an initial state value, it should be set in the *constructor*.

An example would be this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        open: false
    }
}
```

2 things to point out here:

1. You always need to call the base class with super() if you are using a constructor
2. You pass props to the base class if you want to be able to access *this.props* in the constructor. In this case super() would do, since you aren't accessing this.props.

read more [here](http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2016/03/26/683329) and [here](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/should-we-include-the-props-parameter-to-class-constructors-when-declaring-components-using-es6-classes/2781)(from React team directly)